# Get logs of Applications on lan systems

Tags: windows, architecture, wmi

Need to get logs of LAN computers. like when a particular application i.e Photoshop or Microsoft office has opened, created a new file, closed a file, closed an application on LAN.

How to get and implement this monitoring system. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [WMI Tasks: Event Logs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)